# Is it possible to make elements in foundation not wrap around automatically when window width is too small?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am building a website for which I am using `zurb-foundation` for the UI building blocks. However, in some places I want to make the elements in the web non-responsive.

For example, if I have the following code

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-9 columns">
      <div class="my-element">Some elements1</div>
      <div class="my-element">Some elements2</div>
      <div class="my-element">Some elements3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And for `my-element`, I have

```
.my-element {
  float: left;
}
```

Now if I shrink the browser width to a certain width so small that it can't hold all three, the three elements will wrap around into 2-3 lines. I am wondering if there's a way to make it not do that? i.e. have the website in a way such that the user should scroll left and right when the browser width is too small. (Stackoverflow itself is a good example of what I want to achieve :D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is write higher specificity rules which will over ride less specific rules so for example, you can assign a custom class to the container elements like

```
<div class="row custom_wrapper">
  <div class="large-9 columns custom_inner_wrapper">
      <div class="my-element">Some elements1</div>
      <div class="my-element">Some elements2</div>
      <div class="my-element">Some elements3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now you can target these elements like this...

```
.custom_wrapper {
   /* Target .custom_wrapper */
}

.custom_inner_wrapper {
   /* Target .custom_inner_wrapper */
}
```

Now use this to target the child elements like

```
.custom_wrapper .custom_inner_wrapper div:nth-of-type(1) {
   /* Targets 1st div inside .custom_inner_wrapper */
}
```

So this way, these rules will over ride the default rules which will be less specific.

> Note: Ignore using over specific rules as it will affect the
>   performance, as well as you'll end up writing more rules to over ride
>   specific rules.

Comment: would you mind fill in a little bit more details? For example, for `custom_wrapper` should I put in a fixed width? and similarly for the nested wrappers inside that one? What exactly makes the elements non-responsive and not wrap around? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Enzo You need to over ride the styles, so you can assign a fixed width to `custom_wrapper` by using `px`  as the measurement unit

Comment: This answer tells you how to set up your css to prevent the elements from wrapping - but should also indicate what css rules to put inside those classes to prevent the elements from wrapping. It's like you order a sandwich, and when it arrives - it's just the bread!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is simpeler, add this to your stylesheet:

```
.row {
    min-width: 500px;
}
```

`div.row` will now have a minimum width of 500px. When the browser is resized to a size smaller than 500px the scrollbars will appear, and your layout will stay in tact.

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Uc595/)